# How to get char array length when it is used as a byte array and assigned to a char pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, char

When I use a char array as a container of binary data, each item in the array could be a 8-bit integer. How can I get char array length when the array is assigned to a char pointer? Here's an example:

```
// t.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char buffer[3] = {12, 13, -14};
    char * p = buffer;
    printf("%d ", sizeof(buffer));
    printf("%d ", strlen(buffer));
    printf("%d ", sizeof(p));
    printf("%d ", strlen(p));
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(char *));

    return 0;
}
```

The ouput is: 3 6 8 6 8

gdb debugging:

```
(gdb) where
#0  main () at t.c:8
(gdb) p p
$1 = 0x7fffffffe4b0 "\f\r\362\377\377\177"
(gdb) p (char *)buffer
$2 = 0x7fffffffe4b0 "\f\r\362\377\377\177"
(gdb) x/8db 0x7fffffffe4b0
0x7fffffffe4b0: 12      13      -14     -1      -1      127     0       0
```

As you can see, strlen(buffer) is not the array length because follwing memory is not 0. sizeof(p) is not the array length since it's actually the size of a char pointer (64 bit OS).

My question is, when p is passed to another function, how do I get the real array length by p?
Please note the char array in the example is not something like:

```
char buffer[4] = "abc";
```

Comment: `3 6 8 6 8` is hard to imagine, as you only output 4 values...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It's corrected now:char buffer[3] = {12, 13, -14}; printf("%d\n", sizeof(char *));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible.

You need to pass the length as a separate argument.